# Store files send by users on Telegram Bot using Node JS

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Hi I want to store the files send to my Telegram Bot by users to a remote server somewhere. How can I implement this?

Some code I've tried :

```
bot.on('document', (msg) =>{
  fileID = msg.document.file_id;
  const file = bot.getFile(fileID)

  //Produces basic information about the file
  file.then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
  })

  //Not sure what this does but the function returns a file stream
  const fileStream = bot.getFileStream(fileID);

})
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code samples of what you are doing, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've provided some code. Also the file that will be sent is a JSON file.

Comment: And just to be clear, you want to save this on a standard winsows server or are you using something like AWS S3 or Azure storage?